# Unexpected Token - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically I'm trying to create 2 screens on React Native but it won't load because of this "Unexpected Token".
How could I fix it? *It says it's on line 35: "onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Tela02', {name='Tela02'})". Thanks!

`````
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigation} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigation();

const MyStack = () => {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Principal"
                    component={TelaPrincipal}
                    options={{title:'Bem Vindo à tela principal'}}
              ></Stack.Screen>
              <Stack.Screen 
                name="Tela02"
                component={Tela02}
                options={{title:'Bem Vindo à tela 02'}}
              ></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

};

    const TelaPrincipal = ({navigation}) => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button
                    title = 'Ir para Tela 02'
                    onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Tela02', {name='Tela02'})}
                ></Button>
            </View>
        );

    };

    const Tela02 = ({navigation}) => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button
                    title = 'Ir para Tela Principal'
                    onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('TelaPrincipal', {name='Principal'})}
                ></Button>
            </View>
        );

    };

export default MyStack;````
`````

Answer (score 0):

what's the meaning of

```
{name='Tela02'}
```

maybe  it should be

```
 {name : 'Tela02'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update like this:

```
onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Tela02', {name: 'Tela02'})}
```